# "non natural" iso between homotopy and homology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Can we classify all finite CW complexes $X$ such that for each $i$ there is *some* isomorphism $\pi_i(X) \rightarrow H_i(X)$? Note that it is not hard to classify all complexes for which each isomorphism is given by the Hurewicz map.

Comment: @Manuel, do you have a particular motivation for this problem?  The answer is going to be some small class of CW-complexes but I'm not seeing a motivation for the question.  In that regard the title is a little misleading because homotopy groups form a type of graded lie algebra and homology groups don't.  Moreover, you're asking for a dimension-wise isomorphism of groups, not an equality of groups. 

Comment: Would we have to know, a priori, all of the homotopy groups of a space to answer this question?

Comment: The "right" viewpoint on invariants like $H_i$ and $\pi_i$ is that they are *functorial* invariants. It is somehow "wrong" to not think of them functorially. The Whitehead theorem gives some justification for this philosophy.

Comment: Yes, certainly the question sounds like it lacks of motivation, since crazy maps between homotopy and cohomology and not particularly useful. I was just trying to think what is happening geometrically when you have these "non natural" isomorphisms.

Comment: @ Manuel - Just to give slightly different example : A space $X$ and the space $\prod K(\pi_i(X),i)$ have isomorphic homotopy groups. Unless you have a map from one to the other realizing these isomorphisms, there is no geometric meaning to these isomorphisms. The same goes for homology too - given a suitable $X$ you can cook up a product of Moore spaces which have homology isomorphic to $X$. But until you have a map one way or another that realizes these isomorphisms, it is not veru helpful.

Comment: @ Somnath - Yes, this is what "motivated" the question. I am one of the new guys at Sullivan's class at CUNY and after class last wednesday I was wondering if we can get any interesting information about the geometry of the spaces - not the geometric meaning of the isomorphisms- for which some of these isomorphisms are not the given by the natural Hurewicz map...

Answer (score 4):

I also don't see a motivation for this, but anyway: if $i=0$ is allowed, there is not a single example ($\pi_0$ is always finite, $H_0$ never. For the empty space, $\pi_0$ is empty and $H_0$ is not). Apart from $i=0$, the only connected finite CW-complexes with only finitely many (edit: abelian) homotopy groups are tori. (J.-P. Serre, Cohomologie modulo 2 des complexes d’Eilenberg-MacLane, Comment. Math. Helv. 27 (1953), 198-232.)

Comment: Not just tori have finitely many non-trivial homotopy groups (e.g., surfaces of positive genus, etc.).  Do you mean these are the only ones with abelian $\pi_1$?